# Graph of the Probability of blocking vs Traffic intensity

Tags: matlab, math

Good day I have written a code for this question:

> Write a Matlab code to output a graph of the Probability of blocking vs Traffic intensity for 2, 4, 5 10, 20 and 24 trunked channels respectively?

I just wanted to make sure its correct. Could someone please verify that its working fine? Thank you.

```
clear all;
close all;
C=[2 4 5 10 20 24]; % The number of Servers
rho=[0.1:0.1:100]; % Traffic intensity rho = lambda/mu
for i=1:length(C),
 inc=0;
 for q=0:C(i)
 inc=inc+rho.^q/factorial(q);
 end
 pb(i,:)=rho.^C(i)./factorial(C(i))./inc;
end
figure(1)
loglog(rho,pb(1,:),'-b',rho,pb(2,:),'-b',rho,pb(3,:),'-b',...
 rho,pb(4,:),'-b',rho,pb(5,:),'-b',rho,pb(6,:),'-b',rho,pb(7,:),'-b',...
 rho,pb(8,:),'-b');
%% ----------------------------Plotting---------------------------------
xlabel('Traffic Intensity,rho [Erlangs]');
ylabel('Probability of Blocking');
title('Probability of Blocking Vs Traffic Intensity');
axis([0.1 100 1e-4 1]);
text(2.e-1,0.15,'C=1');
text(3.2e-1,3e-2,'C=2');
text(4.8e-1,1e-2,'C=3');
text(7.2e-1,5e-3,'C=4');
text(1,3e-3,'C=5');
text(3.4,1.5e-3,'C=10');
text(9.8,1.6e-3,'C=20');
text(41,1.6e-3,'C=60');
grid on;
%% ------------------------------END---------------
```

Comment: Don't you have some data to compare the results with? Also, the number  of channels from the question don't appear in the code.

Comment: Good day i dont have any, which is why i wanted some help to see if this code is fine

Comment: Assuming you want to implement the Erlang-B formula, you shouldn't use the direct expression with the factorial as that can cause overflow problems for moderately large number of servers. It's better to use the recursive formula: `pb(i) = 1; for k = 1:C(i); pb(i) = 1/(1+k/A/pb(i)); end`

Comment: I used the direct formula because my Traffic intensity (A in Erlang) should in that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about solving   a programming problem.

Comment: i am having an issue im not sure if this is correct